# how to do a aggregate sorting across various django models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 4 models User, Posts, Comments, Friends. Please refer the below models

now I  need an API for the top 10 recent activities done by the user

which can be a combination of all the three
i.e recent posts by the user + recent comments made by the user + recent friend added by the user

or it can be one only comments

or it can be only on posts

or it can only  be friends

basically I need the top 10 recent things done by the user ,

how can I sort this data's by date across the three models and put in a single result list?

so I can pagination to the result list

User model-  stores all details about the users

```
class User(models.Model):
   ......
   ''  ''''
```

Posts model- stores the posts created by the users

```
class Posts(models.Model):
   ......
   ''  ''''
```

Comments - stores the comments made by the users on a post

```
class Comments(models.Model):
       ......
       ''  ''''
```

Friends - stores the friends information

```
class Friends(models.Model):

 ......
   ''  ''''
```

Comment: I would have a separate `user_activity` table

Comment: @casualprogrammer, hey thanks for the suggestion , I am new to django , can you tell me a short design , how can I combine in a singlemodel and query the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

I would have a `user_activity` table

```
CREATE TABLE "uesr_activity" (
    "id" BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    "timestamp" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    "user_id" BIGINT,
    "verb" TEXT, -- perhaps enum
    "object_type" TEXT, -- perhaps enum
    "object_id" BIGINT
);
```

every time you create a post, comment, just also write to this table.

### Option 2

query top 10 from `post` `comments` table, merge/sort in application layer, return combined top 10 to client. In subsequent paginations, using two cursors/ids, query for the next 10 from each table larger than the cursor

Comment: In option 2 after combining the results lets say result =  top 10 posts+top 10 comments +Top 10 friend activties,   How can I sort the top 10 in the result list  by date???

Comment: sort it in application layer, don't need to rely db for everything. Also I recommend the 1st approach